# C - inserting into an existing array

Tags: c, arrays

I have two functions I've already written out, but I'm having trouble incorporating them together. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
//prototypes:
int insert(char *word, char *Table[], int n);

int main(void)
{
    char buf[100];
    char *token;

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);

    token = strtok(buf, " ,.-";

    while(token != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ,.-");
    }
    return 0;
}
int insert(char *word, char *Table[], int n)
{
//*word is the string to be added, *Table is the array, n is the amount of things in array
//after insertion
    #define MAXSTRINGS 5
    #define LENSTRING 100

    int counter = 0;
    n = sizeof(Table)/sizeof(int);

    while(counter < MAXSTRINGS && strlen(Table[counter]))
    {
        if (strcmp(Table[counter], word) == 0)
        {
            return n;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    strcpy(Table[counter], word);
    prinf("\n added at %d", counter);
    return n;
}
```

How can I add an insert function to my main function to take the tokenized strings into the array? For example if I enter "dog is brown" it is tokenized into "dog", "is", "brown" and then I want to insert each of those words into the table. I can't quite wrap my head around it. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you will discard the table after `main` returns, you should be allocating a table structure in `main`, then when you got your token, find out its size and call insert function with your allocated table, token pointer, and its size n.

Comment: I will be writing a third function that `free`s the Table. So no I am not discarding it, but I am emptying it instead.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to insert all the words into a table. You don't need a `insert` function instead you can add a array (`table`) to your main function and then use `strdup` to automagically allocate memory for table. Remember you need to free it afterwards though!

```
token = strtok(buf, " ,.-");

while(token != NULL)
{
  table[i] = strdup(token);
  i++;
  token = strtok(NULL, " ,.-");
}
int j;
for(j = 0; j < i; j++) {
  printf("%s\n", table[j]);
  free(table[j]);
}
```

Comment: sadly this is a homework assignment so I am required to have an `insert` function. I do appreciate your feedback though, as I do need to `free` the table. Followup question: what happens to my string pointers once I have freed the table? How can I set them back to `NULL`?

Comment: @donutjuice This code in the example will print out everything in the block of memory allocated by `strdup` and then essentially free that same block of memory. So you can't read/write from it until you actually allocate memory there again. The table is actually an array of an array where one is static and the other is dynamic.